# Comment notify options confusing for users

Tags: comments, nodes

I am using the [Comment Notify](https://drupal.org/project/comment_notify) module so that users can be notified when someone responds to their comments in forums. On a users account page the options are very confusing - there is a tick-box to receive notifications, and also a drop-down, which only contains two options: "No notifications" and "Replies to my content". The text below the drop-down is also confusing.

Have I got a configuration issue, or is this working as designed?

[image: example]

Comment: Looks to be working by design - the top option is for **content**, the bottom option for **comments**. What does it do differently to what you'd expect, and what specifically in the text are you finding confusing?

Comment: Am I just using it so that users can see when someone responds to their own comments. So they don't have "content" as such, just comments.

Comment: That module provides 2 features - the one you're describing, and one that allows people who _post_ content to be notified when it's commented on, not just when comments are replied to

Comment: In other words, the difference between posting a new item in a forum and responding to someone elses? I do think it is a bit confusing to users, because in both cases it is being notified when someone responds to one of your posts/comments - I don't think users are going to understand the difference between a post and a comment in a forum.

Comment: Comment notify is written for Drupal as a whole, not for the forum module. Nodes (content) and comments are very different things in Drupal. If your users aren't going to understand that, I'm not sure what you're going to be able to do (apart from hook in to the form and change the text, obviously) - that's how Drupal is built. To answer your question, though: no, you haven't got a configuration issue, and yes the module is working exactly as designed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments: no, you haven't got a configuration issue, and yes the module is working exactly as designed.

If your users are likely to find that confusing, you can use [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) in a custom module/theme to change the text to something that makes more sense. Or even hide one or more of the options altogether, if that's what you need.

Comment: Clive, Thanks very much for your responses. Yes, I think I will make changes to the text of the form using  hook_form_alter() to make it clearer.